# Adding type in a function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

Suppose I define a function:

```
const nonEmpty = (str: string) => str.length > 0;
```

Now I'm adding a type to `nonEmpty` like that:

```
const nonEmpty : (str: string) => boolean = (str: string) => str.length > 0;
```

It compiles but I don't like that the argument name (`str`) appears *twice*. Moreover, the argument name does not make sense to add an argument name to the function *type*.

I would prefer `const nonEmpty :  string => boolean = ...` or similar. Is it possible in Typescript ?

P.S. I found another way to declare a function type:

```
 const nonEmpty = (str: string): boolean => str.length > 0;
```

It looks more concise but a bit strange for an inexperienced Typescript developer. Would you prefer this type declaration ?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to omit second `string` type:

```js
const nonEmpty : (str: string) => boolean = (str) => str.length > 0;

nonEmpty('hello') // ok
nonEmpty(1) // error
```

Second option:

```js
type NonEmpty = (a: string) => boolean
const nonEmpty: NonEmpty = (str) => str.length > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also note that typescript can automatically infer the type definition, so you might not need to explicitly add it at all.

[image]

Comment: Sure but I do want to add the type (and use a "linter" to check it)